# Pressing menu button causes crash in Activity with no ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

I'm a newbie in Android and working on my first app.

I have the main activity with no `ActionBar` in it. And I don't want to display any menu in that `Activity`. Everything is working just fine But when I press the menu button present in the device itself, it causes my app to force close instead of just ignoring it.

I'm developing for sdk >=8 so I'm using the support library. I have tried adding `OnCreateOptionMenu()` in the code with nothing in it but ended up with same results.

The name of my app is GUI and the package is gui. Here is the Logcat:

```
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplICS.java:274)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.getMenuInflater(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:89)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.getMenuInflater(ActionBarActivity.java:71)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2554)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:224)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:141)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:280)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:453)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDownPanel(PhoneWindow.java:853)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDown(PhoneWindow.java:1535)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2052)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3924)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3872)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3007)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
10-09 19:52:32.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7440):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can't figure out what's the cause of this error. Please help me to locate it. If any other info is needed then plz let me know.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

My guess is that this is a bug in the AppCompat library. If you take a look at the code for ActionBarImplICS.getThemedContext() you see that it's the mActionBar that is null:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarImplICS.java#ActionBarImplICS.getThemedContext%28%29

My guess is that you're using an activity without a title (and thus also without an actionbar):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

If I remove this and launch the activity with a title/actionbar I haven't been able to reproduce the crash. Now, running the app with a titlebar when you don't want or need one isn't a very good option. My suggestion is that you override the Menu key press. The app stopped crashing for me when I did this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        // do nothing
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: That just worked perfectly for me. Yes i had created a custom theme for my activity with no title bar. And as u rightly pointed, the cause of the error was most probably the getThemedContext() function. Thank you so much for your help. I hope this would come handy to others as well.

Comment: In case someone bumps into the same problem: I am using a TabMenu, so I had to add this code in ALL the views in order to actually catch the event.

Comment: @britzl: My doubt is, I have implemented the same actionbar for other activity also. Then why it is not crashing over there?

Comment: I mean without actionbar. It is working everywhere except a particular activity, where there was actionbar before I modified to no actionbar.

Comment: Sorry I didn't check it properly. It is there in all other activity.

Comment: @britzl, I am using navigation drawer with action bar, and adding searchview on the activity, its crash with NPE on
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this will be fixed in the next support library release http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61394