# App crash when press MENU button

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

My android app is using support v4 library:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:maxSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

And it is just created as a new project. When I run it on my phone and press the menu button, it crashes:

> 12-21 15:12:54.170  31705-31705/com.talkweb.woplus E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplICS.java:287)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplJB.java:20)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.getMenuInflater(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:98)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.getMenuInflater(ActionBarActivity.java:71)
>               at com.talkweb.woplus.HomeActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(HomeActivity.java:35)
>               at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2652)

code in HomeActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  // I add this line
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        webViewFragment = new WebViewFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, webViewFragment)
                .commit();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);  // line: 35
    return true;
}
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    </style>
</resources>
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.talkweb.woplus">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:maxSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity
            android:name="com.talkweb.woplus.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.talkweb.woplus.HomeActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Show your `R.menu.home` layout.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275447/oncreateoptionsmenu-causing-error-in-an-activity-with-no-actionbar

Comment: Dumping your code on SO and asking "What's wrong" in unlikely to produce anything but close / down votes. P.S. there's *exactly* one reason for a `NullPointerException`. The reference you're trying to use is `null`

Comment: @laalto It explained why, that's great but, what if I need to show options menu without ActionBar?

Comment: @GrIsHu menu layout added.

Comment: If you don't have an action bar, where are you going to show the menu options?

Comment: Remove this line `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` from your code and then check @JSPDeveloper01

Comment: @laalto A menu popup from bottom, you know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on analysis in the question "[Pressing menu button causes crash in Activity with no ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275447/oncreateoptionsmenu-causing-error-in-an-activity-with-no-actionbar)", this is because the action bar is null. And that's because of this:

> ```
> requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  // I add this line
> ```

which removes the action bar among other things.

Now, your requirements are conflicting: you want a menu but you don't want an action bar. A "menu popup from bottom" is not something you can have, at least not using the standard Android components. You'll have to choose between:

1. Action bar and menu, removing the `FEATURE_NO_TITLE`.
2. No action bar, no menu, keeping the `FEATURE_NO_TITLE`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @laato, with your help I finally find out that all I need to do is make my HomeActivity NOT extends `ActionBarActivity` but normal `Activity`. Now my options menu shows up.