# Crash on longpress of edittext in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, long-press

I have an edit text. While I am trying to long press on edittext the app crashes,
it gives the following log:

```
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at  android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplICS.java:302)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplJB.java:20)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.getActionBarThemedContext(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:208)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onActionModeStarted(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:195)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onActionModeStarted(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:359)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2342)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2260)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:654)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:654)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:654)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:654)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:654)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:654)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:4519)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.widget.Editor.startSelectionActionMode(Editor.java:1524)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:845)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:8268)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:17882)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
08-12 10:42:51.503: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have no idea why it's happening.

Comment: post code of EditText

Comment: The actionbar is null. Does your app theme have one?

Comment: i am using this line, requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
can it be a problematic?

Comment: without your code snippet we can to realize what is wrong with your code can you please post your code ?

Comment: ok i got the solution, my activity was extending ActionBarActivity and i just replaced it with Activity and it working fine. Thank you all for your attention and help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275447/pressing-menu-button-causes-crash-in-activity-with-no-actionbar/19320065#19320065)

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        // do nothing
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: @RajeshSuthar this issue seems to be fixed in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61394..please make sure you are using latest version of library

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need getSupportActionbar() other than getActionbar()

Answer (score 0):

I have study about this problem and found that this problem is android OS bug and for solve that in your `values/styles` remove below code:

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">every things here</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

`IF` your `EditText` is wrapped with a `TextInputLayout` this may help you

It the `TextInputLayout` has a `theme` assigned make sure that its parent is

`parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"`

This was my issue and after changing the parent it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what worked for me...

1) If your EditText is wrapped with a **TextInputLayout** then add below property to your Edittext

> **android:longClickable = false**

2) If you are using a custom style for your EditText then add below attribute to your custom style code.

```
<item name="android:longClickable">false</item>
```

Hope this helps.